# Latency in a cog in Discord.py isn't recognized as a valid attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

At first when I was creating all my commands for my discord bot in one single file without reorganizing it in cogs, everything worked very well. Now that I created cogs (and placed my ping command there), my program no longer recognizes "latency" as an attribute. The rest of my commands (ban, unban, kick, clearText) weirdly enough still function properly without any errors.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class basicComs(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f"Pong {round(commands.latency * 1000)}ms")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(basicComs(commands))
```

The error message is:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: module 'discord.ext.commands' has no attribute 'latency'
```

Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because discord.ext.commands has no latency attribute. The latency attribute still belongs to your client, which is `discord.ext.commands.Bot`

So even after moving to cogs, you still have to call latency off your client. Also you're not adding the Cog to your client on the last line.

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def ping(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(f"Pong {round(self.client.latency * 1000)}ms")

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(basicComs(client))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but it somehow still shows the same error message.

Comment: @wurstm162 Sorry, I didn't catch it earlier, check your last line: `client.add_cog(basicComs(commands))` <-- should be `...(basicComs(client)` Editing my answer